# mypy complains about Sequence[Parent] when the list holds multiple Child classes

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a base class `A`, and several classes `B` and `C` which inherit from it.

If I try to create a list with the hint `Sequence[A]` and assign to it `[B()]`, there's no issue. Same with `[C()]`. But if I try to assign both, Pycharm and mypy complain with the following error:

```
error: List item 0 has incompatible type "C"; expected "B"
```

[image]

Where the most simple example is:

```py
class A:
    pass


class B(A):
    pass


class C(A):
    pass


b: Sequence[A] = [B()] + [C()]
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I?

Comment: `[B()]` is inferred as `List[B]` for the concatenation *before* assignment to `b`.

Comment: Your question says the variable is annotated as ``List[A]``, but the code shows ``Sequence[A]``. Which is it?

Comment: Note that ``List`` is invariant, so ``a: List[A] = [B()]`` *should* be invalid. Strangely enough, mypy 0.782 accepts it for some reason but then rejects ``a: List[A] = [B()] + []``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you're right, I should've clarified. Both give the same error in mypy however (though using `List` adds an additional one).
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56758285/978089) indeed answers the question. Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, I ended up splitting the commands into to separate lines: `a: List[A] = [B()]` and then `a.append(C())`, and this seems to work. Not sure how it differs from the other cases, but there we are.