# Expected type 'List[A]' (matched generic type 'List[_T]'), got 'List[B]' instead on correctly typed lists

Tags: python, python-typing

```
from typing import List


class Base(object):
    pass


class A(Base):
    pass


class B(Base):
    pass


a: List[A] = []
b: List[B] = []
c: List[Base] = a + b
```

I am getting `Expected type 'List[A]' (matched generic type 'List[_T]'), got 'List[B]' instead` on `b`.

How do I get correct warnings, as obviously the types are fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a warning when concatenating lists of mixed types in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738485/why-do-i-get-a-warning-when-concatenating-lists-of-mixed-types-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These types are not fine. `List` is invariant, meaning that a `List[X]` is *not* a substitute for `List[Y]` unless `X` and `Y` are exactly equal. Similarly, `A <: Base` does not imply `List[A] <: List[Base]` and likewise for `B`.

> #### [PEP 484: Covariance and contravriance](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance)
>
> [...]
> By default generic types are considered invariant in all type variables, which means that values for variables annotated with types like `List[Employee]` must exactly match the type annotation -- no subclasses or superclasses of the type parameter (in this example `Employee`) are allowed.

While it is possible to re-interpret the types for this operation, this is not unambiguous. A conservative type checker will reject the operation instead of guessing.

---

A mutable container such as `List` is invariant because elements can be both *inserted* into (contravariant) and *taken* from (covariant) the list. If mutability is not required, using an immutable [Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) provides valid type annotation:

```py
from typing import Sequence

a: Sequence[A] = []
b: Sequence[B] = []
c: Sequence[Base] = [*a, *b]
```

If mutability is desired, one can explicitly enumerate all the types to be found in the `List`. This pre-emptively widens the elements to be expected in the list, even if each individual list actually contains only one type.

```py
a: List[Union[A, B]] = []
b: List[Union[A, B]] = []
c: List[Union[A, B]] = a + b
```

Pre-emptively widening the type of the operands may be undesirable or impossible. Alternatively, one can [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) them at the site of usage.

```py
a: List[A] = []
b: List[B] = []
c: List[Union[A, B]] = cast(List[Union[A, B]], a) + cast(List[Union[A, B]], a)
```

Note that `cast` effectively disables type checking for the cast'ed value. Only use it in cases that are known to be correct.