# How do I make a type annotation for a list of subclass instances, e.g to concatenate two lists?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I want to iterate over `List[A]` and `List[Subclass of A]` and do the same loop. The best way I can see to do that is to concatenate the two lists. However, mypy is not happy about it.

How can I concatenate the two and keep mypy happy?

Currently, I do `# type: ignore[operator]`. I would like to avoid that, if possible.

### MVCE

```py
# Core Library modules
from typing import Iterable

# Third party modules
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Animal(BaseModel):
    height: float
    weight: float


class Cat(Animal):
    lives: int = 7


cats = [Cat(height=1, weight=2, lives=7), Cat(height=3, weight=2, lives=1)]
animals = [Animal(height=9, weight=9)]

combined: Iterable[Animal] = cats + animals

for animal in combined:
    print(animal)
```

gives

```
$ mypy untitled.py
untitled.py:20: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("List[Cat]" and "List[Animal]")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected type 'List\[A\]' (matched generic type 'List\[_T\]'), got 'List\[B\]' instead on correctly typed lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481378/expected-type-lista-matched-generic-type-list-t-got-listb-instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation occurs because `list` is [invariant](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#invariance-vs-covariance) (provides an illustrative example).

I can offer two solutions:

1. Explicitly define both lists as `List[Animal]` for successful concatenation:

```
cats: List[Animal] = [Cat(height=1, weight=2, lives=7), Cat(height=3, weight=2, lives=1)]
animals: List[Animal] = [Animal(height=9, weight=9)]
combined: Iterable[Animal] = cats + animals

for animal in combined:
    print(animal)
```

2. Use [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) for consecutive iteration:

```
cats = [Cat(height=1, weight=2, lives=7), Cat(height=3, weight=2, lives=1)]
animals = [Animal(height=9, weight=9)]

for animal in itertools.chain(cats, animals):
    print(animal)
```

Comment: No, `combined` contains *instances* of `Animal`, but not *class objects* `Animal`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Updated my answer with typing.Sequence

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't bother you, change `List` to `Sequence`

```
from typing import Sequence

class Base: pass

class Derived(Base): pass

ds: Sequence[Derived] = [Derived()]
bs: Sequence[Base] = ds
```

with which you'll get

```
$ mypy temp.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```