# How to write correct typings for join of two python lists with elements having same parent

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I have pydantic models, which share same base class

```
class Base(BaseModel):
    shared_arg: str

class A(Base):
    some_arg1: int

class B(Base):
    some_arg2: str
```

I have a function, which accepts `list[Base]` as an argument. I want to combine `list[A]` and `list[B]` together in order to pass it inside this function and operate on their `shared_arg` values.

Assume, function is

```
def work_on_bases(values: list[Base]) -> list[str]:
    return [v.shared_arg.upper() for v in values]
```

and lists look like this:

```
list_a = [A(shared_arg='hello', some_arg1=0), 
          A(shared_arg='world', some_arg1=5)]

list_b = [B(shared_arg='green', some_arg2=7), 
          A(shared_arg='horse', some_arg2=9)]
```

I've tried to make something like this

```
combined: list[Base] = list_a + list_b
```

and this

```
list_a_base: list[Base] = list_a
list_b_base: list[Base] = list_b
combined: list[Base] = list_a + list_b
```

But pylance (pyright) still issues

```
Operator "+" not supported for types "list[A]" and "list[B]"
```

Is there a way to write correct typings here or `# type: ignore` is the only way to go?

Comment: can you add the part of the code where you define list_a, list_b?

Comment: and besides that, it seems you haven't implemented `__add__` at all/correctly in Base or BaseModel

Comment: Updated with list examples. I don't need to have `__add__` in Base in order to join lists. I don't make addition between values inside lists.

Comment: Code has no issues with functionality, but typings are not checked correctly

Comment: Have you tried using it outside of pylance? I'm using regular python 3.9(via conda environment) and this works fine

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64604214/how-do-i-make-a-type-annotation-for-a-list-of-subclass-instances-e-g-to-concate/64605151#64605151

Comment: StrangeSorcerer, question is not about functionality (it works just fine), but about type checking

Answer (score 0):

This work perfectly with `mypy`.
If you don't specify the type on `list_b` the checker will assume a list of `Object` but if you specify the type all will work as expected.

Note that there are a few issue in the initialization of `listb` in your example (`B.some_arg2` expects a `str` and `A` doesn't have `some_arg2` attribute)

```
class Base(BaseModel):
    shared_arg: str

class A(Base):
    some_arg1: int

class B(Base):
    some_arg2: str

list_a: list[Base] = [A(shared_arg='hello', some_arg1=0), 
          A(shared_arg='world', some_arg1=5)]

list_b: list[Base] = [B(shared_arg='green', some_arg2='7'),
          A(shared_arg='horse', some_arg1=9)]

combined: list[Base] = list_a + list_b
```