# Avoiding typing errors in Python for `[Subclass()] + [BaseClass()]`

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I'm trying to combine lists of compatible classes together as follows:

```py
class BaseBlock:
  pass

class MarkdownBlock(BaseBlock):
  pass

def get_standard_blocks() -> List[BaseBlock]:
  return [BaseBlock()]

blocks = [MarkdownBlock(f"Some text")] + get_standard_blocks()
```

This causes a typing error:

```
Expected type 'list[MarkdownBlock]' (matched generic type 'list[_T]'), got 'list[BaseBlock]' instead
```

What is the idiomatic way to fix this?

Comment: What type do you expect ``blocks`` to be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected type 'List[A\]' (matched generic type 'List[_T\]'), got 'List[B\]' instead on correctly typed lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481378/expected-type-lista-matched-generic-type-list-t-got-listb-instead)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi List[BaseBlock]

Comment: It's a similar issue, but not quite the same. Here I'm not explicitly defining the first lists type so I would expect the type checker to be a little smarter

Comment: I'm afraid no level of smartness lets the type checker know whether you wanted a ``list[BaseBlock]`` or ``list[Union[BaseBlock, MarkdownBlock]]``. (That's not to say the other question helps with that either, necessarily.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi isn't the latter included in the former?