# Why isn't this Protocol derived from another Protocol recognized as a valid return type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a Protocol that looks like the following:

```py
class Thinglike(Protocol):
    start: str
    end: str
```

And, I have a protocol that has a method which returns a list of objects of the type of this protocol. It looks something like this:

```py
class Actorlike(Protocol):
    def get_props(self) -> List[Thinglike]: pass
```

I also have another protocol derived from the `Thinglike` protocol:

```py
class AnotherThinglike(Thinglike, Protocol):
    additional_attribute: str
```

And, another protocol that is derived from the `Actorlike` protocol:

```py
class AnotherActorlike(Actorlike, Protocol):
    additional_attribute: str
    def get_props(self) -> List[AnotherThinglike]: pass # complains here
```

Python does not recognize `AnotherThinglike` as compatible with `Thinglike` in my return signature on `get_props`, why?

Comment: What type checker are you using? mypy? What error does it give you exactly? I tried filling in the blanks and got `Return type "List[AnotherThinglike]" of "get_props" incompatible with return type "List[Thinglike]" in supertype "Actorlike"`

Comment: You are not returning a Thinglike but a List[Thinglike]. List is invariant since it can be modified.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Having played around with this and the below for past couple days, I think something related to this invariance issue is the better solution. I've found that just switching to `Sequence[Thinglike]` and noting that you must construct your desired sequence around the returned sequence appears to be a viable pattern thus far. But, I'm curious if you have something better that you might want to provide as an answer.

Comment: ``Sequence`` is the way to go for the use case here, see also [Expected type 'List\[A\]' (matched generic type 'List\[_T\]'), got 'List\[B\]' instead on correctly typed lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481378/expected-type-lista-matched-generic-type-list-t-got-listb-instead). However, there's nothing wrong with combining Protocol with a TypeVar as in the current answer; the power of Python's ``typing`` system is that it isn't constrained to only one typing model.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are not returning `ThingLike` but an extended version of it. If you want to be able to return inherited versions of `ThingLike`, you have to switch to using generics and TypeVars with an explicitly defined upper bound. That upper bound should be `Thinglike`, which means return this class or any that inherited from that class. In code

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

class Thinglike(Protocol):
    start: str
    end: str

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Thinglike)


class Actorlike(Protocol[T]):
    def get_props(self) -> list[T]: pass

class AnotherThinglike(Thinglike, Protocol):
    additional_attribute: str

class AnotherActorlike(Actorlike, Protocol):
    additional_attribute: str
    def get_props(self) -> list[AnotherThinglike]: pass # shouldn't complains here
```

If you want to check it out, [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.931&python=3.10&gist=a7419bc3ec1a5aa09fde0acf72fd8fef) you can playaround with it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! This seems odd since Protocol is supposed to be for structural subtyping. Doesn't this behavior skew a bit more nominal?