# mypy return type of tuples of various length

Tags: python, mypy

Here is some mock code:

```
def my_func() -> set[tuple[str, ...]]:
    my_set: set[tuple[str, str]] = set()
    # do some stuff
    return my_set
```

Running mypy on above code gives the error:

```
Incompatible return value type (got "Set[Tuple[str, str]]", expected "Set[Tuple[str, ...]]")
```

Why is `set[tuple[str, str]]` not recognized as a `set[tuple[str, ...]]`?

In production, I have several functions of the above form, and each function returns a set of homogenous tuples (`my_func2` would return a set of 5-tuples, and `my_func3` would return a set of `11-tuples`). I would like the return type to be the same for my family of functions `my_func, my_func2, my_func3`.

Comment: I guess the issue is that ``set`` is invariant. [This is a common point of confusion for ``list`` as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481378/expected-type-lista-matched-generic-type-list-t-got-listb-instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` is invariant, meaning that the type parameters have to match exactly, rather than one simply conforming to the other.  The simplest fix here is to just annotate `my_set` with the desired return type:

```
def my_func() -> set[tuple[str, ...]]:
    my_set: set[tuple[str, ...]] = set()
    my_set.add(("foo", "bar"))
    return my_set
```

Another option (if you want `my_set` to be limited to 2-element tuples within the body of the function) would be to `cast` it when you return:

```
from typing import cast

def my_func() -> set[tuple[str, ...]]:
    my_set: set[tuple[str, str]] = set()
    my_set.add(("foo", "bar"))
    return cast(set[tuple[str, ...]], my_set)
```

However, note that the *reason* that sets are invariant is that they are mutable.  Suppose you pass `my_set` (as a set of 2-tuples) to another (more picky) function that expects it to only ever contain 2-tuples, and then return a reference to `my_set` that's been cast so that it can contain n-tuples.  Now anyone with that cast reference can insert n-tuples into it, which violates the typing assumptions of the more picky function!  This is why `cast` can be dangerous -- in this case it's safe only as long as no reference to `my_set` with its 2-tuple typing persists after the `return`.

So if you want `my_set` to be typed as a 2-tuple, but you want to return a set of n-tuples, another option is to return a `frozenset`:

```
def my_func() -> frozenset[tuple[str, ...]]:
    my_set: set[tuple[str, str]] = set()
    my_set.add(("foo", "bar"))
    return frozenset(my_set)
```

Returning a `frozenset` ensures that the caller will not be able to mutate `my_set` and violate its 2-tuple typing.

Note that returning an anonymous (mutable) copy is also perfectly safe (I think), but mypy won't deduce that, so you still have to `cast` it explicitly:

```
    return cast(set[tuple[str, ...]], my_set.copy())
```